# Parallel loop in winrt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, winrt-async

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    for (long i = 0; i < bound / 10; i++)
    {
        routeLine.Locations.Add(new Location
        {
            Latitude = ((BingMapsRESTService.Route)(r.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0])).RoutePath.Line.Coordinates[k][0],
            Longitude = ((BingMapsRESTService.Route)(r.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0])).RoutePath.Line.Coordinates[k][1]
        });

        k++;
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));

    Temp("Drawing Route (" + ((j * 10)/2).ToString() + "%)"); // to show progress,Temp sets text property of a textbox
}
```

Bound has value between 6000 to 10000. This loop takes time and hang the UI that's why i divided the loop into 10 parts and used task.delay. 
Is it possible to run all ten loops in parallel? I can't use thread as I can't create object of Location class in new thread. It throws an error of task being marshaled by some another thread

Comment: what is `routeLine.Locations` ? are you sure it is thread-safe to `Add` ? if not, you will have to synchronize. Frankly, I don't see that this is going to be useful to parallelize. Building the composed line *in the background*, *sure* - just start a task to build the loop on a worker, then "await" the task. But that is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible; you can use TPL and `Parallel.ForEach`:

[TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

[Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx)